# Use kml polygon from fusion table to polygon variable in containsLocation

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to use kml polygons from Fusion table retrieved by code

```
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({query: { select:'\'geometry\'', from: 'myFusionTable'} });  
    layer.setMap(map);
```

in myFusionTable are rows id,name,geometry.
I need to check which kml polygon contains MyPoint, but have not idea how to do this using

```
var isinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(MyPoint,kml_polygon);
```

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: You can query the fusion table to determine that information; you can't access the polygons loaded in the FusionTablesLayer.

Comment: So should I use ST_INTERSECTS ?